# Cannot init constructor in xamarin bindings

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin

I'm trying to create an object of the class i mapped.

```
  [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
  interface LibClass
  {
    // @property (readonly) NSString * key;
    [Export("key")]
    string Key { get; }

    // @property (readonly) NSArray * blockNames;
    [Export("blockNames")]
    //[Verify (StronglyTypedNSArray)] //TODO: Verify
    NSObject[] BlockNames { get; }
  }
```

But code `new LibClass();` throws exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: -init is not a valid initializer for the class LibClass.

This is code of generated constructor

```
 [CompilerGenerated]
 [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
 [Export ("init")]
 public LibClass () : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty)
 {
   IsDirectBinding = GetType ().Assembly == global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.this_assembly;
   if (IsDirectBinding) {
     InitializeHandle (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, global::ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("init")), "init");
   } else {
     InitializeHandle (global::ApiDefinition.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, global::ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("init")), "init");
   }
 }
```

Comment: You can not create an instance of an `interface`. What is `LibClass`? You define it twice: as `class` and as `interface`. Name them differently to make it clearer.

Comment: "The API Definition file: will only contain namespaces and interface definitions (with any members that an interface can contain) and should not contain classes, enumerations, delegates or structs. The API definition file is merely the contract that will be used to generate the API." http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/ . This is only mapping. I'm not trying to create instance of interface.